# how to use gsub() to remove a complex string patterns

Tags: r, gsub

I had a table of data looks as following:

```
| _ - 9 | PR - Very happy with results. | Improvement - Be more clear regarding how the entire process works. I.e. how long you have to wait for your account to become active. | Churn Reason - none"
```

I try to delete `| Improvement...|` from each row if there is one. I wrote the it as

```
feedback <- gsub("| Improvement*|", "",data$Feedback,  ignore.case = FALSE, perl = TRUE)
```

But it does nothing. Is anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the pipe characters `|`, because they are interpreted as OR. You also need a `.` for the `*` quantifier to apply to. Finally, although it does not matter for this example, you probably want the non-greedy version of `*` so that you don't collect more than one field worth of stuff.

```
Feedback = "| _ - 9 | PR - Very happy with results. | Improvement - Be more clear regarding how the entire process works. I.e. how long you have to wait for your account to become active. | Churn Reason - none"  
feedback <- gsub("\\| Improvement.*?\\|", "", Feedback,  ignore.case = FALSE, perl = TRUE)
print(feedback)
```

Output:

```
"| _ - 9 | PR - Very happy with results.  Churn Reason - none"
```